# Match and extract zipcode in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string like  HONOLULU HI 96814-2317 USA and sometimes HONOLULU HI 96814 USA . I want to extract only the zipcode i.e., 96814-2317 and 96814 from the string in javascript . How can i achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Try a regex?

Comment: i tried to do a search on string zip.search(^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$") . This isn't working for me.

Comment: Use \\d{5}(?:[-\\s]\\d{4})? . It will work

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli  You can check here .. I save the regex for you to validate https://regex101.com/r/kaOpMM/1

Comment: @Vidura this will return me the matching index. How will i extract that zip from string.

Comment: Use The exec() method which executes a search for a match in a specified string. Returns a result array. I have posted  the running code in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Running code.

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str1 = 'HONOLULU HI 96814 USA';
var str2= 'HONOLULU HI 96814-2317 USA';
var pattern=/\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?/;
var result1 = pattern.exec(str1);
var result2 = pattern.exec(str2);
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = result1;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = result2;
}
</script>
<p id="result1"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
</html>
```